# C++ Not showing second set of info entered

Tags: c++

I can not for the life of me understand why this is not showing the class info for each class I take.  I have been working on it since I was here asking about the other thing last night. I dont get what to do or why it is not working, when it displays the info it only displays it for the second class

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct Classroom{
int Studn;
int Studn1;
int RoomNum;
string lname;
string StudList;
int Chairs;
bool window;
bool projector;
bool availability;
};
void classinfo1(Classroom& clss, vector<string> Stud);
void output(Classroom& clss, vector<string> Stud);
void classinfo2(Classroom & clss1, vector<string> Stud1);
void output1(Classroom & clss1, vector<string> Stud1);


int main()
 {
vector<string> test;
vector<string> test1;
Classroom now;
Classroom now1;
float a, b;


classinfo1(now,test);
classinfo2(now, test);
output(now,test);
output1(now, test);



system("pause");
return 0;
 }

 void classinfo1(Classroom& clss, vector<string> Stud){


string answer;



cout << "Please enter the first classrooms info\n";
cout << "Room number\n";
cin >> clss.RoomNum;
cout << "Lecture name\n";
cin >> clss.lname;
cout << "number of chairs in the class\n";
cin >> clss.Chairs;
cout << "How many students is in your class?\n";
cin >> clss.Studn;

for (int i = 0; i < clss.Studn; i++){
    cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << endl;
    cin >> clss.StudList;

    Stud.push_back(clss.StudList);

}
cout << "Does the class have a window?" << endl;
cin >> answer;
if (answer == "Yes" || answer == "yes" || answer == "YES"){
    clss.window = true;
}
if (answer == "no" || answer == "No" || answer == "NO"){
    clss.window = false;
}
cout << "is the class available?" << endl;
cin >> answer;
if (answer == "Yes" || answer == "yes" || answer == "YES"){
    clss.availability = true;
}
if (answer == "no" || answer == "No" || answer == "NO"){
    clss.availability = false;
}
cout << "does it have a projector?" << endl;
cin >> answer;
if (answer == "Yes" || answer == "yes" || answer == "YES"){
    clss.projector = true;
}
if (answer == "no" || answer == "No" || answer == "NO"){
    clss.projector = false;
}



 system("cls");
 }

 void output(Classroom& clss, vector<string> Stud){


cout << "\n\n\n";
cout << "Class one info\n";
cout << "Room number:" << clss.RoomNum << endl;
cout << "Lecture Name:" << clss.lname << endl;
cout << "Num of Chairs:" << clss.Chairs << endl;
cout << "Num of Students:" << clss.Studn << endl;
cout << "Student names:" << endl;

vector<string>::iterator studorder;

sort(Stud.begin(), Stud.end());
for (studorder = Stud.begin(); studorder < Stud.end(); ++studorder){
    cout << *studorder << endl;
}
if (clss.window){
    cout << "window : yes" << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "window: no\n";
}
if (clss.availability){
    cout << "availability : yes" << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "availability : no\n";
}
if (clss.projector){
    cout << "projector : yes" << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "projector : no\n";
}
 }

void classinfo2(Classroom & clss1, vector<string> Stud1){

string answer1;



cout << "Please enter the second classrooms info\n";
cout << "Room number\n";
cin >> clss1.RoomNum;
cout << "Lecture name\n";
cin >> clss1.lname;
cout << "number of chairs in the class\n";
cin >> clss1.Chairs;
cout << "How many students is in your class?\n";
cin >> clss1.Studn;

for (int i = 0; i < clss1.Studn; i++){
    cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << endl;
    cin >> clss1.StudList;

    Stud1.push_back(clss1.StudList);

}
cout << "Does the class have a window?" << endl;
cin >> answer1;
if (answer1 == "Yes" || answer1 == "yes" || answer1 == "YES"){
    clss1.window = true;
}
if (answer1 == "no" || answer1 == "No" || answer1 == "NO"){
    clss1.window = false;
}
cout << "is the class available?" << endl;
cin >> answer1;
if (answer1 == "Yes" || answer1 == "yes" || answer1 == "YES"){
    clss1.availability = true;
}
if (answer1 == "no" || answer1 == "No" || answer1 == "NO"){
    clss1.availability = false;
}
cout << "does it have a projector?" << endl;
cin >> answer1;
if (answer1 == "Yes" || answer1 == "yes" || answer1 == "YES"){
    clss1.projector = true;
}
if (answer1 == "no" || answer1 == "No" || answer1 == "NO"){
    clss1.projector = false;
}



}

 void output1(Classroom & clss1, vector<string> Stud1){


cout << "\n\n\n";
cout << "Class Two info\n";
cout << "Room number:" << clss1.RoomNum << endl;
cout << "Lecture Name:" << clss1.lname << endl;
cout << "Num of Chairs:" << clss1.Chairs << endl;
cout << "Num of Students:" << clss1.Studn << endl;
cout << "Student names:" << endl;

vector<string>::iterator studorder1;

sort(Stud1.begin(), Stud1.end());
for (studorder1 = Stud1.begin(); studorder1 < Stud1.end(); ++studorder1){
    cout << *studorder1 << endl;
}
if (clss1.window){
    cout << "window : yes" << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "window: no\n";
}
if (clss1.availability){
    cout << "availability : yes" << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "availability : no\n";
}
if (clss1.projector){
    cout << "projector : yes" << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "projector : no\n";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void classinfo1(Classroom& clss, vector<string> Stud){
```

passes `Stud` by value.  In other words, it passes a copy of `Stud` that is only available inside `classinfo1`.  The vector in calling code is unaffected.

If you want to edit the caller's vector, you should pass by reference instead

```
void classinfo1(Classroom& clss, vector<string>& Stud){
//                                             ^
```

The same applies for `classinfo2`.  You should presumably also pass your second vector - `test1` to that.  You currently pass the same vector to both functions, meaning that details for both classes are combined into a single array.

```
classinfo2(now, test1);
```

Comment: I tried that bro and it still only shows one of the class info at the end, both outputs are the same at the end which i dont get

Comment: That doesn't match your code.  Are you sure you've posted the correct code.  Regardless, I've updated my answer with another problem which probably accounts for this second issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass vectors by reference to functions classinfo1 and classinfo2

```
void classinfo1(Classroom& clss, vector<string> &Stud);
void classinfo2(Classroom & clss1, vector<string> &Stud1);
```

Take into account that there is no any sense to define data member `StudList` in structure `Classroom` because it is always overwritten in functions classinfo1 and classinfo2 in the code snippet

```
for (int i = 0; i < clss.Studn; i++){
    cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << endl;
    cin >> clss.StudList;

    Stud.push_back(clss.StudList);

}
```

It would be better if you would remove this data member from the structure and use a local variable of type std::string in the loop shown above.

Comment: @simonc you are brilliant bro thank you so much, it freaking sucks that something so simple has halted me for 12 hours lol  thank you very much again